# How do I run Phantasy Star Universe on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, phantasy-star-universe

I bought PSU awhile back when I still had XP, after upgrading to Vista some time ago I can't get it to run. All I get now is a Japanese Error Message.

Has anyone run into, and fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, though I don't have the game so I can't confirm, you can do the following things to get it to work:

- Right-click the shortcut or executable and go to the compatibility tab, and set it to run in Windows XP SP3 (or earlier) compatibility.
- Go to the Windows Firewall settings (in the control panel) and in the Exceptions, add the PSU executable (C:\Program Files...)
- You may have to disable any antivirus or firewall software that you are running, as several things (notably ZoneAlarm) seem to conflict with the [GameGuard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NProtect_GameGuard) anti-cheating mechanism that the game uses.

Alternatively, you could buy and install the expansion pack, "Phantasy Star Universe: Ambition of the Illuminus" - its [system requirements](http://phantasystaruniverse.com/illuminus_info.php) include Windows Vista so it should be compatible.

If none of the above works, I would [contact Sega](http://www.sega.com/support/) and see if they can help you any more.